# Using custom flash messages, and calling them. (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, html, flash-message

Okay, so I am only currently trying to figure out how show certain types of messages in EJS. I am using this now, which works:

```
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    db.query(sql, [username], function(err, rows) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (!rows.length) {
        return done(null, false, {
          type: 'loginMessage',
          message: 'Login',
        });
      }

      //  Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err)
          return done(err);
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, rows[0]);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            type: 'loginMessage',
            message: 'Wrong Login',
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

That's where the messages come from. However I am having issues rendering them 1 type at a time.

```
<%- messages('msg_temp', locals) %>
```

Is how I'm doing it, but that shows every type. I would like to have two of these, one above login and one above register with `'loginMessage'` as the login type and `'regMessage'` as the register type.

Is you want to see exactly what I'm trying to do, you can go to https://playkog.net

If you try to register itll show the messages above login. (etc etc).

Comment: Where is your node code? where is your ejs code??

Comment: Added in the OP, I understand that the messages.loginMessage isn't a function.

Comment: While your code is not `PHP`, I added the tag in case someone there can answer such _database querying within a webpage_ issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out HALF my answer. I was able to put a type for my messages. Using this code:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (isMatch) {
      return done(null, rows[0]);
    } else {
      return done(null, false, {
        type: 'loginMessage',
        message: 'Wrong Pass',
      });
    }
```

However, I am still not sure how to call specific types on messages on the same page. I have a login and register form on my front page. So I would like `'LoginMessage'` to show above my login form and `'regMessage'` above the registration form. I just don;t know how to show these types in different lines of code, as I get an error if I use two `messages()` functions